# One page scrolling site using relative or absolute URLs with # anchor links?

Tags: url, seo, anchor, hashtag

For SEO purposes can should in page anchor links be written absolute or relative?

I've always read (for the most part) that it's better to absolute URL's for your website as opposed to relative ones for SEO purposes.

However, I am currently creating a one page site and am trying to make it as SEO friendly as possible since there is only the one page.

I was curious as to whether or not using absolute URL's would also benefit in this situation when using anchors to scroll to sections of the page or if it would hurt it. I haven't been able to find any info on this.

So, assume I have a link on my main navigation that will scroll to a section on the page:

```
<a href="#about>About Us</a>
...
...
...
...
...
...
<section id="about">
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>This section would be the equivalent to an about us page except since it is only a one page site, it shows on the homepage in a section.</p>
</section>
```

What I'm wondering is that instead of the link I used above would I benefit from this instead:

```
<a href="http://example.com/#about>About Us</a>
```

I know that this is the proper way to do it when linking to another page, but I'm more concerned about the same page. Wouldn't the second one be better for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever. Whoever told you that absolute links are better for SEO has no clue!

The only thing I would advise is to ensure that you code URLs correctly and don't make mistakes such as sending out a relative URL or linking to a relative URL on someone else's site, which can end up in wrong URLs such as http://www.stackoverflow.com/posts/www.externalsite.com

Comment: How would you link to a relative url on someone else's site exactly?

Comment: I've seen javascript do things to relative URLs that cause uncrawlable links. Also, using relative urls you are adding another layer of processing for spiders which has to figure out the absolute url which could cause issues, no? Don't lot of 404 issues, canonicalization issues, migration issues, or when the base is set to something else, stem from relative urls, which would essentially be bad for seo? (These are things I've heard/read)

Comment: @Candid I meant situations where you'd pick up the relative URL from another site and plop it onto your page, ending up in a normal internal link on your site to a page that doesn't actually exist.

From an SEO point of view, all the situations you mentioned should be taken care of if you're just careful with your internal linking.